# Unbound Local Error: local variable referenced before assignment inside of a try and except statement

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a very simple menu system, using all of the pythonic tools, (try and except statements, loops, if statements) and I have run into a little bit of trouble.

This is the code and error message i have at the moment

```
def Menu():
while True:
    print("""
    Hello, please enter a number 1 - 4
        1 - Compliment
        2 - Fact
        3 - Insult
        4 - Quit
        """)

    try:
        UserInput_INT = int(input("> "))


    except ValueError:
        UserInput_STR = (UserInput_INT)
        if len(UserInput_STR) == 0:
            print("You have entered nothing. Please enter a number between 1 and 4")
        print("You entered a character. Please enter a number between 1 and 4")
        Menu()

    if  UserInput_INT not in range (1, 5):
        print("Invalid input please enter a whole number between 1 and 4")
        continue

    UserInput_STR = (str(UserInput_INT))
    if UserInput_STR == '1':
        print(" You look horrible today!")

    elif UserInput_STR == '2':
        print("Sam Birkenshaw & Jordan Ives can code better than Mr Bath. ")

    elif UserInput_STR == '3':
        print("You are bad at coding ")

    elif UserInput_STR == '4':
        quit()
```

Menu()

error message:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/All/School Work/Computer Science/Code/SAM broken code.py", line 12, in Menu
    UserInput_INT = int(input("> "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/All/School Work/Computer Science/Code/SAM broken code.py", line 39, in 
    Menu()
  File "E:/All/School Work/Computer Science/Code/SAM broken code.py", line 16, in Menu
    UserInput_STR = (UserInput_INT)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'UserInput_INT' referenced before assignment"

I need to have it so that if the user enters nothing, there is a different message displayed than if they enter a letter, and if they enter something other than one of the accepted answers.

(I am runing python 3.6.2 currently)

Comment: Please put your code and output as code-formatted text directly in your question body, not as images. We can't run an image.

Comment: Your code is **text**, post it as such. Images can't be read by screenreaders, can't be indexed and can't be copied into a text file to be tested.

Comment: code put in a quote

Comment: Why use recursion *and* a while-loop? Also, what is the error message?

Comment: the while loop is only used to ensure the code loops on itself, it isnt necisary.  and the error message has been added to the code.

Answer (score 0):

The value that is being passed as input to the program is not a valid integer. Now, when an exception is raised the variable `UserInput_INT` is not being assigned causing the second error. Try checking if the value is integer before trying to cast it.

```
input = input("> ")
UserInput_INT = int(input) if input.isdigit() else input
```

As a side note, please try to follow naming conventions.